# Translate two points from one axis to another?

Tags: matrices, vectors

**What I know**

Original two points that establish a box (points are opposite corners):

P1 = (-3,3,1)

P2 = (3,3,15)

Starting axis (at origin):

X vector = (1,0,0)

Y vector = (0,1,0)

Z vector = (0,0,1)

**What I wish to do**

I wish to move my box to my new coordinate system which is shown below:

X vector = (0.9616,-0.0006,-0.2745)

Y vector = (-0.0008,-1,-0.0003)

Z vector = (-0.2745,0.0005,-0.9616)

What is a simple way to translate my box coordinates systematically? The given numbers above are just one example I have, mostly to ensure that the new axis uses unit vectors.

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried to use the translational matrix formula:
[image]

to solve for A, B and C which coorespond to my new vector, resulting in Rz, Rx, and Ry with respect to my image. From there I have tried to then use my angles to translate my two points. However, the resulting points I get are either correct, mirrored across an axis, or flipped. Is there a simpler way to calculate this or am I going about it the right method at least?

**Visual example**

[image]

Coordinate system in red is the coordinate relative to the box. The Z axis needs to align with the new Z axis, Y with the new Y, and Z with the new Z, moving the box with it

Comment: Are you trying to “drag” the points along with the coordinate axes as you change them to the new ones, or are you trying to find the coordinates of the points relative to the other axes?

Comment: @amd I am trying to "drag" them along with the new coordinate system. I added a picture which hopefully helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A handy fact to remember when trying to solve such problems is that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. Thus, the matrix that maps that standard basis to the new $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ vectors is simply $$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0.9616 & -0.0008 & -0.2745 \\ -0.0006 & -1.0000 & 0.0005 \\ -0.2745 & -0.0003 & -0.9616 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Apply this matrix to your points to find where they end up as they’re dragged along with the coordinate axes by this transformation. For your two sample points this gives $$M\begin{bmatrix}-3\\3\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3.1617\\ -2.9977\\ -0.1390\end{bmatrix} \\ M\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\\15\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1.2351\\ -2.9943\\ -15.2484\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: The transitional matrix is where I got the vectors from. What I am having a hard time with is the part where you say "apply this matrix to your points". How can I achieve this?

Comment: @EricF You just left-multiply the coordinate vector of the point by the matrix.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much!